# Get the value of radio button using material-ui for summary page

Tags: material-ui, radio-button

I'm creating a form and now attempting to get the value for a summary page.
I'm not having trouble in selecting the radio buttons. The problem lies in getting the value of radio button in material-ui for a summary page/print the value.

The following are my code:

```
 Registering Office: <br></br>
     <Grid container direction={'row'} spacing={1}>
       <Grid item xs={3}>
   
                <Radio id="RegOffice"  value="Head Office" checked={RegOffice==="Head Office"} onChange={handleChangeRegOffice}
                  color="primary"
                 
                />
   
         
          Head Office
       </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
                <Radio id="RegOffice"   value="Branch Office" checked={RegOffice==="Branch Office"} onChange={handleChangeRegOffice}
                  color="primary"  />
          Branch Office
         </Grid>
     <Grid itemxs={3}> 
                <Radio id="RegOffice"  value="Facility" checked={RegOffice==="Facility"}
                  onChange={handleChangeRegOffice}
                  color="primary"   //label="Facility"
                />  
          Facility 
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

for handlechange:

```
    const [RegOffice, setRegOffice] = React.useState('Head Office')
const handleChangeRegOffice = (event) => { setRegOffice(event.target.value)
console.log(RegOffice) }
```

=end=

With no luck, every time I call "RegOffice", it always returns blank value.

Appreciate any help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine, but you're doing `console.log(RegOffice)`, before the state is updated. React set/update state Asynchronously, which means when you're viewing the `console.log(RegOffice)` the `regOffice` state still contains the old state value. The updating state is a really vital React concept and learning about it will be very beneficial for creating/understanding the React Code. Here is a [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) link

I've created the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-radio-button-s4ij3?file=/src/CustomComponent.js) link out of your code and just moved the `console.log()` outside the `handleChangeRegOffice` function.

```
const handleChangeRegOffice = (event) => {
    setRegOffice(event.target.value);
};
console.log(RegOffice);
```

the updated function and console statement